# How to take fields from parent dataframe into its subset in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been working on json to flatten it. I have flattened the json and got all feilds

I have a parent dataset with 4 columns:---firstname, last_name, gmail, age

and a child subset extracted from parent subset using filter(filter heighest age age) and group by(group by gmail) .

now columns I'm getting for subset is :-max age

max_age and gmail

Now what I want is using this below subset, I want to extract all columns that are present in subset from parent set

How can this be done.... Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want dataframe like this - FirstName, LastName, Gmail, Age (max)

Answer (score 0):

You can join based on both 'age' and 'gmail'

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([["Amy","Santiago", 32, "good99@gmail.com"],["Rosa", "Dias", 31,"good99@gmail.com"],["Norm", "Skully", 50,"bad99@gmail.com"]]).toDF("Name", "LastName", "Age", "Gmail");
```

[image: Input]

This would work

```
df_agg = df.alias("df1")\
.join(df.groupBy("gmail").agg(F.max("Age").alias("Age")).alias("df2"), F.col("df1.Age").eqNullSafe(F.col("df2.Age")) & F.col("df1.Gmail").eqNullSafe(F.col("df2.Gmail")))\ # Join
.selectExpr("df1.*")\ # Select only Df1 columns
.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you please let me know how to fill a empty cell with null/none or any string . I know the opposite when it's null to fill with null

Comment: @Nishanaik Empty values as in? can you give an example? Usually when statement works but can see what is the exact requirements.